# .htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, redirect, url

I have an existing Wordpress site setup at mycompany.tld1 and recently registered mycompany.tld2.

I want to setup a 301 redirect from mycompany.tld2 to mycompany.tld1, what would that .htaccess file look like? Can I append it to the Wordpress .htaccess file using a conditional statement to check the inbound URL?

WP .htaccess (existing):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` would look a bit like this if you wanted to do a 301 redirect from `mycompany.tld2` to `mycompany.tld1`.

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectPermanent / http://mycompany/tld1/
</IfModule>
```

Comment: RedirectPermanent is in mod_alias, not not_rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect all domains that are not your primary:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.tld1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.tld1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirect only the secondary TLD to the primary:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.tld2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.tld1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In your .htaccess file, I would suggest placing these right below `RewriteBase /`